# react-native-community/slider value can be handled by text box and viceversa?

Tags: react-native

[image: slider with editable textbox whenever i am editing the text box slider value is setting to 0 Expected is slider also should move to 58]
So my app demands the use of slider whose value can be given by sliding or by text box and viceversa . I am not able to understand whenever i am printing value in text its printing but when i put it inside text box its not printing ,same whenever i am typing number in text box slider value is not changing.
Here is my code

```
export const Slider = props => {
const [value, setValue] = useState();
//  const [isTouchEnded, setIsTouchEnded] = useState(false);

return (
<View style={styles.content}>
  <Slider
    style={styles.slider}
    minimumValue={0}
    maximumValue={100}
    value={value}
    minimumTrackTintColor="#00E487"
    maximumTrackTintColor="#00E487"
    onValueChange={e => setValue(e)}
    step={1}
  />
  <View>
    <TextView>{value}</TextView>
    <TextBoxInput
      testID="tiDimLevel"
      style={styles.textBox}
      keyboardType="numeric"
      value={value}
      returnKeyType="next"
      onChangeText={e => setValue(e)}
      maxLength={3}
    />
  </View>
</View>
);
[slider with editable textbox whenever i am editing the text box slider value is 
setting to 0 Expected is slider also should move to 58]};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a ref to slider and then create a useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   sliderRef.current.setNativeProps({ value: +value });
}, [value])
```

Comment: its not working tried this also    <TextBoxInput
        
          onChangeText={value => {
            setValue(value);
            slider.current.setNativeProps({ value: value });
          }}
     
        />